# Matlab's sparse svd function

Tags: matlab

I am using svds from Matlab. It is working great, exactly what I need -- except for... It is in Matlab...

I would like to know what kind of implementation they use and whether it is available in  other languages. Is that possible to find out?

Comment: Specify the language in which you need to use svd....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can inspect any fundtion in matlab using edit. For example,

```
 edit svds
```

Comment: Not quite true. Yes, you can inspect any m-file. But many of the tools in MATLAB are compiled code. So while svds is available for you to read, eig for example, is not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Matlab uses the ARPACK library as a backend. You can find bindings to this library for other languages such as C, Fortran, [Python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html), etc.